# $\mathbb{Z}_2$-grading by Hodge star operator (for signature theorem)

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, differential-topology, hodge-theory, differential-graded-algebras, index-theory

This question may be a bit low level for MO but I have not received any attention from [the SE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3574419/mathbbz-2-grading-by-hodge-star-operator).

Consider the algebra of exterior forms $\bigwedge T^*M$ on an even dimensional $n$-manifold $M$. We can form an operator $\sigma=\bigoplus_{k=1}^ni^{k(n-k)}*_k:\bigwedge T^*M\rightarrow\bigwedge T^*M$ (where $*_k$ is the Hodge star restricted to $\bigwedge^k T^*M$). This operator is known as the *signature operator* and satisfies $\sigma^2=1$.

In index theory (particularly in regards to the Hirzebruch signature theorem) it is commonly stated that this gives a $\mathbb{Z}_2$-grading on $\bigwedge T^*M$ by decomposing into $\pm1$ eigenspaces of $\sigma$. However, I cannot see how this makes sense away from the restriction to $\bigwedge^{n/2} T^*M$. Given an arbitrary $\alpha\in\bigwedge T^*M$ it does not follow that $\sigma\alpha=\pm\alpha$ unless either $\alpha\in\bigwedge^{n/2} T^*M$ or $\alpha$ is in the **vector space** $\bigwedge^p T^*M\oplus\Lambda^{n-p} T^*M$.

Any help reconciling this grading would be much appreciated.

Comment: Use *stars* `*stars*`, not $\textit{math-mode fakery}$ `$\textit{math-mode fakery}$`, for italics.  I was in the middle of editing, but @YCor beat me to it.  (I'd still like to see the semantically correct $\bigwedge$ `$\bigwedge$` in place of $\Lambda$ `$\Lambda$` ….)

Comment: Anyway, it's not clear what your question is.  We have a $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$-grading on each summand of $\bigoplus_{k = 0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor} V_{\pm i}$, where $V_{\pm n/2} = \bigwedge^{n/2}T^*M$ and $V_{\pm i} = \bigwedge^iT^*M \oplus \bigwedge^{n - i}T^*M$ for $i \ne n/2$; and then we sum the components of the individual constituents to get a $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$-grading on the whole algebra.  What is the problem?  (Notice that $\sigma\alpha = \pm\alpha$ doesn't follow for $\alpha$ in the indicated spaces, either; only that $2\alpha = (1 + \sigma)\alpha + (1 - \sigma)\alpha$.)

Comment: I agree with what you say, but maybe I am not understanding something basic. If you have a $\mathbb{Z}_2$-grading on each of the above components how does this give a $\mathbb{Z}_2$-grading on the algebra? For example, if I take $\alpha\in \left(V_{\pm i}\right)^+$ and $\beta\in \left(V_{\pm j}\right)^-$ then what $\pm$ component of the $\mathbb{Z}_2$-graded algebra does $\alpha+\beta$ lie in?

Comment: A $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$-graded algebra $A$ is, at least in my understanding (and I think that of the problem) not an algebra in which *every* element is labelled '+' or '-', but an algebra $A$ in which *some* elements are labelled '+' or '-', so that the sets $A_\epsilon$ of elements labelled $\epsilon$ are subgroups, and such that $A = A_+ \oplus A_-$ (not $A = A_+ \cup A_-$) and $A_{\epsilon_1}A_{\epsilon_2} \subseteq A_{\epsilon_1\epsilon_2}$.

Comment: Oh yes of course. Thank you.